# Define Overviews Tool Error when Iterating through Mosaic Datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, mosaic, error-999999

[image]

I have multiple mosaic datasets in a file geodatabase. I need to run the [Define Overviews](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-overviews.htm) tool on all the mosaic datasets. However, when I try to iterate through the mosaic datasets with ModelBuilder I get an error after the first iteration, meaning it can't move on after the first mosaic dataset.

I had thought the problem was the output workspace since mosaic dataset overviews are are generated and stored in a folder next to where the mosaic dataset resides. Thus the output location is not in Testing.gdb but in a Testing.Overviews folder with sub-folders for the overviews of each mosaic dataset. So, I was attempting to solve the output workspace location problem with this model.

I'm not sure how to solve the output workspace location problem because the it should be 
C:\RasterTests\Testing.Overviews\%Name%.Overviews

I am also not sure the output workspace location is even the problem.

[image]

[image]

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Executing (Iterate Datasets): IterateDatasets C:\RasterTests\Testing.gdb Block2* MOSAIC NOT_RECURSIVE
>   Start Time: Thu Jun 29 10:12:40 2017
>   Succeeded at Thu Jun 29 10:12:40 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.51 seconds)
>   Executing (Define Overviews): DefineOverviews C:\RasterTests\Testing.gdb\Block270 C:\RasterTests\Testing.Overviews\Block270.Overviews # "196299.9918 6325479.8683 315300.8666 6525992.993" # # 5120 5120 3 NO_FORCE_OVERVIEW_TILES BILINEAR JPEG 80
>   Start Time: Thu Jun 29 10:12:41 2017
>   2017-06-29T10:12:42.370: Defining overviews
>   2017-06-29T10:12:42.371: Computing default overview pixel size
>   2017-06-29T10:12:42.443: Defining overviews for pixel size: 1.875
>   2017-06-29T10:12:43.057: Defining overviews for pixel size: 5.625
>   2017-06-29T10:12:43.452: Defining overviews for pixel size: 16.875
>   2017-06-29T10:12:43.484: Defining overviews for pixel size: 50.625
>   2017-06-29T10:12:43.511: Defining overviews for pixel size: 151.875
>   2017-06-29T10:12:43.539: Defining overviews for pixel size: 455.625
>   Succeeded at Thu Jun 29 10:12:43 2017 (Elapsed Time: 2.27 seconds)
>   Executing (Iterate Datasets): IterateDatasets C:\RasterTests\Testing.gdb Block2* MOSAIC NOT_RECURSIVE
>   Start Time: Thu Jun 29 10:12:44 2017
>   Succeeded at Thu Jun 29 10:12:44 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.45 seconds)
>   Executing (Define Overviews): DefineOverviews C:\RasterTests\Testing.gdb\Block280 C:\RasterTests\Testing.Overviews\Block280.Overviews # "196299.9918 6325479.8683 315300.8666 6525992.993" # # 5120 5120 3 NO_FORCE_OVERVIEW_TILES BILINEAR JPEG 80
>   Start Time: Thu Jun 29 10:12:45 2017
>   2017-06-29T10:12:46.308: Defining overviews
>   2017-06-29T10:12:46.308: Computing default overview pixel size
>   ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   Failed to execute (Define Overviews).
>   Failed at Thu Jun 29 10:12:46 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.93 seconds)

Comment: Is one of the mosaics empty?  Have you tried putting a variable into the name of the output mosaic?  A lot of ArcGIS tools break if you try to write a new file or feature class to a location with an extant file of the chosen name.

Comment: @P.T.Curran No, the mosaics are not empty. I'm not sure what you mean by putting a variable into the name of the output mosaic. How do I do that?

Comment: %'s are used to denote variables.  So set the output Mosaic name to something like Mosaic_%Name%, set the Name oval as a prerequisite to Define overview, then try running it.

Comment: @P.T.Curran I re-made the model. It's still not working but I'm not sure I did it like what you meant.

Comment: Have you checked that your workflow works when you take the iterator out of your model?  If so, I think you should include details of not just what does not work, but also that to demonstrate that all but the last bit added does work.

Comment: @clair0girl, you already have a variable in your model: %Name%.Overviews.  Maybe try something similar with the name of the output Mosaic?  Try basing it off the Name variable.